# What triggers these wordpress queries on my homepage?

Tags: wp-query

I am trying to clean up my wordpress theme and I want to know what triggers the following questions on my blog homepage.

First - do I need this on my homepage?:

```
SELECT user_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id IN (1)

require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/baracuda/index.php'), setup_postdata, get_userdata, get_user_by, WP_User->init, WP_User->for_blog, WP_User->_init_caps, get_user_meta, get_metadata, update_meta_cache
```

Second:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE ID = '1'
```

Comment: Can you also copy the part of your html/php code just so that I can understand where exactly these snippets are used.

Comment: Do these queries fire when you are not logged in? _If_ you are logged in WordPress makes a look-up for the current user – hence the user queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the queries themselves displayed or are the results displayed? If the results of those queries are being output onto your homepage it's a potential security vulnerability.

The query returns user data including username and password hash for user ID 1 of the wp_users table, which is the administrator user that Wordpress creates when first installing.

I recommend changing the administrator's password and removing the code from the homepage, and checking other template files for similar code.

Also its generally a bad practice to run SQL queries in theme files, as there are built-in functions in Wordpress for accessing user data.